# Calling an Api with React

Tags: reactjs

So I want to call an API with react and my data is not showing up correctly I know I did it right but is there anything I am missing because I don't know why it is still showing Loading

[image: Web screenshot]

```
   import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      students: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3200/students")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((myresult) => {
      this.setState({
           isLoaded: true,
           students: myresult.students,
      });

  },
  (error) => {
    this.setState({
         isLoaded: true,
         error
    });
  }
)
}
render() {
    const {error, isLoaded, students} = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
    } else if (isLoaded) {
      return <div> Loading ...</div>
    } else {
  return (
    <ul>
      {students && students.map(student => (
       <li key={student._id}>
          {student._id} {student.role_num}

       </li>
      ))}
  </ul>

  );
}
}
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to display information from this URL http://localhost:3200/students

> I was following this link on how to call an API https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html
>   hey guys updated my code I am still getting the same issue stuck on loading I don't know whether I am passing in my data properly

Comment: I guess that by `MountComponent` you meant `componentDidMount` right ? Although, you are never setting the `students` property in your `state`

Answer (score 1):

I think there a couple of things going on here but main points are

- its `componentDidMount` not `MountComponent`
- your not setting `students` correctly in state

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
} else if (!isLoaded) {
```

to:

```
} else if (isLoaded) {
```

Comment: @Arnald see my answer

Comment: can you console log myresult ?

Comment: .then((myresult) => {

Answer (score 0):

In you code above for MountComponent see that you are setting up movieItems and your state is expecting students. To solve the issue use the code below.

```
MountComponent = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3200/students")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((myresult) => {
      this.setState({
           isLoaded: true,
           students: myresult.students,
      });

  },
  (error) => {
    this.setState({
         isLoaded: true,
         error
    });
  }
)
  }
```

Comment: he never calls MountComponent on his code, so you are right about students but still, this is a partial answer. either tell him to change it to CDM or tell him where and how to invoke it

Comment: @Roy.B so I have updated my code and posted it on SO but still get loading

Comment: @Arnald that's because the if(!isLoaded), change it to if(isLoaded)

Comment: @Roy.B ok fixed it now I get this error  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: In your render function above you do not validate whether students is defined or not. change the code in render method as below

What i added is students && before students.map


do this and try in your code 

<ul>
      {students && students.map(student => (
       <li key={student._id}>
          {student._id} {student.role_num}
       </li>
      ))}
  </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your function and check

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3200/students").then(res => {
  this.setState({ students : res.data })
  })
}
```